# 3 Author but only 1 Author per Frame

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer class document with the Darmstadt theme. In this document I have 3 authors, but I will only show 1 per Frame in the upper left box for the authors. The authors for a frame is changing (author 1 makes frames 1-5, author 2 makes 6-10 and so on). How can I implement this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}

\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{BeamerColor}
\usepackage{s4ndm4n}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=burlywood1}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}

\title{Title}   

\author{author1 \and
author2 \and
author3} 
\date{01.01.2017}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Schluss}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Schluss}
\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
Vielen Dank für Eure Aufmerksamkeit!
\end{Large}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Diskussionsrunde}
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge}
Diskussionsrunde
\end{Huge}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? There is no "upper left box for the authors" in Darmstadt theme by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}

\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{BeamerColor}
\usepackage{s4ndm4n}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=burlywood1}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}

\title{Title}   

\author{author1 \and author2 \and author3} 
\date{01.01.2017}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\author{name1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\author{name2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\author{name3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\author{author1 \and author2 \and author3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Schluss}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```